# Trying to make presence of at least one optional parameter required, but its presence excludes the others

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

so let me dive into an example:

```
type NodeOrMethod<T> =
    | {
          node?: Array<Filter<T>>;
          method: Condition<T>;
      }
    | {
          node: Array<Filter<T>>;
          method?: Condition<T>;
      };

interface BaseFilter {
    label: string;
    value?: string;
}

export type Filter<T> = BaseFilter & NodeOrMethod<T>;
```

Basically what I want to do is make it so the dev has to either include `node` or `method` - which this currently works; however, I want to take it a step further and say IF one of these is present the other CANNOT be. So if they try to include both `node` and `method` in the same object it would complain. Has anyone done something like this before?

Comment: Just remove the optional type?

Comment: @JonasWilms that doesn't seem to work. If I add both Node and Method it doesn't complain.

Comment: hmm. I'm always doing `{ type: "one", stuff } | { type: "two", other }` and that works. Seems that the union type is like an "OR", and is only exclusive if both types are mutualy excluding each other.

Comment: What happens if you do `method: never` (unfortunately im AFK so I can't try it myself)

Comment: @JonasWilms Hmm, I've never used `never`, I just tried it and it blew some stuff up, but I might have it formatted weirdly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use tagged unions (see the relevant section of the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)) for what you are trying to do, something like

```
type Node<T> = {
    type: 'node',
    node: Array<Filter<T>>;
}
type Method<T> = {
    type: 'method',
    method: Condition<T>;
}
type NodeOrMethod<T> = Node<T> | Method<T>;

cost a: NodeOrMethod<T> = { // valid
  type: 'node',
  node: [...]
}

cost b: NodeOrMethod<T> = { // valid
  type: 'method',
  method: ...
}

cost c: NodeOrMethod<T> = { // type error
  type: 'method',
  node: [...],
  method: ...
}
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20NodeT%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'node'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20node%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MethodT%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'method'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NodeOrMethod%3CT%3E%20%3D%20NodeT%3CT%3E%20%7C%20MethodT%3CT%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20NodeOrMethod%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'method'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method%3A%20123%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%3A%20NodeOrMethod%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'node'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20node%3A%20123%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20c%3A%20NodeOrMethod%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'method'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20node%3A%20123%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I feel like this should work for me, but for some reason it's not. It's still allowing both `node` and `method` to be present. It just complains when neither are there. Granted I don't have the `type` property on there.

Comment: I've added a link to a (simplified) playground demo

Comment: "I don't have the type property on there" thats what makes it mutualy exclusive.

Comment: @JonasWilms okay so I need to have a property like that to explicitly say which one is on there?

Comment: Yes kind of. But I don't know the actual semantics of the union type to give an adequate answer (I'm still waiting for one of those ts goldbadgers to arrive), but e.g. `{ exists: true, stuff } | { exists: false, other }` would also work

Answer (score 0):

Node/JS philosophy doesn't really work this way. Objects are given permission to have whatever they want on them and consuming code only pays attention to what it cares about. Some ways to handle this include:

- Use factory methods to ensure proper instantiation of your objects
- Have a "type" property that indicates whether to look at the node or the method

All the same, the type is suspiciously overloaded with two meanings. I expect there is another pattern available that avoids this. If you're stuck in a corner with code that is not yours, then one of the above approaches should work fine.

Comment: Your first paragraph makes not much sense when talking about Typescript, as objects do have a certain shape. Factory methods would help to enforce a certain shape, but so do proper typings. "the type is suspiciously overloaded" oh well, thats what Typescript is all about.

Comment: @JonasWilms Typescript does nothing to ensure an object doesn't have properties I don't expect. Consider extending the object, or using type intersection. Typescript intends to ensure an interface is available, that's it. Not that it's *not* available. It doesn't do this because it's nonsense to try and a confusion of compile-time and runtime concerns.